# How to do indentation in spring-tool-suite?

Tags: coding-style, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation, spring-tool-suite, sts

I want to do indentation of all the cluttered code. Please let me know what could be the shortcut to do so?

I'm expecting the shortcut key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the Java source editor, select the `Source` menu group, and choose `Correct Indentation`. The keyboard shortcut should show up on the right side of the menu item.